# Explain the "Decision" element in salesflow

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, traveling-salesman, salesforce-communities, salesforce-service-cloud

Allows you to evaluate a set of conditions,and route the users through the flow based on the outcomes of those conditions.The element actually performs an if-then statement.When a flow executes a Decision element,it evaluates each decision outcome in order.

Thoughts on their mind.

Comment: And? What is your question? It's config, not code related isn't it? What is this, some job interview challenge?